# Reading integers from console

Tags: elixir

I am creating a "choose your own adventure" style game, and I am having trouble finding a decent solution for storing user answers (that are numbers) as integers.

My solution:

```
 age = IO.gets("enter age: ")
 n = String.strip(age)
 new_age = String.to_integer(n)
```

Then I have the age as an integer; however, it takes the above two functions to convert the input. There must be a better way. I tried using `IO.getn` but the problem I ran into there is that one has to specify the `count` after the `prompt`, but what if one does not know how large or small the number the user enters is? I cannot seem to find anything in detail regarding how to handle user input for console applications.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an idea

```
{age, _} = IO.gets("enter age: ") |> Integer.parse
```

Comment: works, but why? A complete noob, thanks!

Comment: @Hank We're using the pipe operator (`|>`) to get the result of the `gets` function call and feed it as the first parameter of the function `Integer.parse/2` . This function then returns a tuple consisting of the integer as the first element, and the rest (non-integer) part as the second element if there is any. That is what we are matching against using the match operator (=). The first element will be the age as an integer, and the second element is discarded using `_` in the match. Check out the [documentation for this function](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2) to learn more.